# Cryptic error messages with npm and node

Tags: node.js, npm, reactjs, zsh, react-native

I'm following facebook's tutorial on getting started with React Native (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#hello-world), but I can't get the react-native-cli to install. Any help interpreting the error messages? Obviously it says to unlink something, but I don't know what it is linked to that it shouldn't be linked to.

Running as root seems to do *something*, but zsh still won't recognize the react-native command.

```
➜  ~  npm install -g react-native-cli
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! path /Users/bbarclay/.node/bin/react-native
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/bbarclay/.node/bin/react-native'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/bbarclay/.node/bin/react-native']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/bbarclay/.node/bin/react-native' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/bbarclay/.node    /bin/react-native'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/bbarclay/.node/bin/react-native']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/bbarclay/.node/bin/react-native' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/bbarclay/npm-debug.log
➜  ~  sudo npm install -g react-native-cli                
Password:
/Users/bbarclay/.node/bin/react-native -> /Users/bbarclay/.node/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
react-native-cli@0.1.4 /Users/bbarclay/.node/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
└── prompt@0.2.14 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.6, winston@0.8.3, utile@0.2.1)
➜  ~  react-native init AwesomeProject
zsh: command not found: react-native
```

Comment: *"npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."* permissions error. open your cmd prompt as an administrator.

Comment: I ran the command as root as well, which didn't bring up any errors but also didn't give me access to the react-native-cli. And the info about linking makes me think running with sudo would just be a workaround to the real issue anyway..

Comment: the linking issues are also permissions problems. It was unable to delete files used during the installation when the installation failed, thus leaving a partial install.

Comment: Are you in windows? i assumed windows due to your path. Do other globally installed npm cli modules work?

Comment: ha forgot to mention anything about my environment. I'm on OSX. I installed just the node cli tool to check if other modules work, and it seems they do. should i remove npm and do a clean install?

Comment: It's worth a try, couldn't hurt. Try clearing npm cache too.

Comment: Weird, I installed node via brew and react native went in easy.  you must have some weird permissions going on.

Answer (score 0):

Add the admin permission to .npm home directory.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```